# PHP Laravel insert into MySQL DB rare symbols

Tags: laravel, symbols

I have symbols like: , and when I try to insert them to UTF-8 DB I get error:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x8E\xAE\xD0\x9F...' for column 'desc' at row 1
```

is any method to convert such symbols and insert to mysql DB?

Comment: Why are you trying to insert a controller glyph into a date time column?

Comment: Why do you insert it into datetime field???

Comment: Field type is text, not datetime

Comment: That's not what the SQL query says. Have a look at your insert statement again and make sure it's good

Comment: You need to provide more of your code, the insert code as well as the database migration/schema.

Comment: Migration and save method: https://jpst.it/MC_0

Comment: utf8 isn't enough...you want your table/column to support utf8mb4 encoding (we went through this last year). See this article: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Comment: changing table and Laravel settings to utf8mb4 solved the problem, thanks.